# Laravel Routing View Cache

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

Im facing a weird problem in Laravel 5.7

I have several routes which load a DashboadController.
Yesterday I has this controller rendering the views like so:

```
@home -> view('dashboard-home') -> /resources/views/dashboard-home.blade.php
@account-> view('dashboard-account') -> /resources/views/dashboard-account.blade.php
@company-> view('dashboard-companies') -> /resources/views/dashboard-companies.blade.php
@companyBrands -> view('dashboard-company-brands') -> /resources/views/dashboard-company-brands.blade.php
@brand-> view('dashboard-brand') -> /resources/views/dashboard-brand.blade.php
```

Today I changed to this, and created the dir strucutre as represented bellow, with the respective blade files:

```
@home -> view('dashboard.home') -> /resources/views/dashboard/home.blade.php
@account-> view('dashboard.account') -> /resources/views/dashboard/account.blade.php
@company-> view('dashboard.company.list') -> /resources/views/dashboard/company/list.blade.php
@companyBrands -> view('dashboard.brand.list') -> /resources/views/dashboard/brand/list.blade.php
@brand-> view('dashboard.brand.edit') -> /resources/views/dashboard/brand/edit.blade.php
```

When i access the @home route it works as expected (it renders the correct blade file, /resources/views/dashboard/home.blade.php)

But when I access the other views I get a exception saying `View [dahsboard-account] not found` or `View [dahsboard-companies] not found`. I was expecting laravel app to render the newest views

I've read somewhere that I should run `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`. It doesnt seem to work, still have the same behaviour.

Then I started changing the project and tested it like so:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/account', function () {
    echo 'aaaaa';
})->middleware('auth');
```

Instead of

```
Route::get('/dashboard/account', 'DashboardController@account')->middleware('auth');
```

It still throws the same exception mentioned before.
I tried running `php artisan route:clear`, nothing changed, still trying to execute the `DashboardController@account`.

Its been 2h30 trying to figure this out, but with no luck...
Any tips would be appreciated.

Best Regards and happy programming!

Comment: Is this local?  Are you using php opcache?  None of Laravel's caches should affect what the controller returns.

Comment: @Devon yes, it is local, and no opcache doesnt seems to be enabled, i checked it right now in `php.ini` and its commented like so: `;opcache.enabled=1`

Comment: What happens if you change one of the errors back to the `dashboard-account` structure? You might have spelling error in `[dahsboard-account]` in the dahsboard -> should be dashboard

Comment: yes, i did before and right now. `php artisan route:list` seems to detect the DashboardController methods, but the one i changed to `echo 'aaa'`, still shows as DashboardController@account, this should show `Closure` I guess

Comment: You put the `echo 'aaa'` in the route definition or the controller?

Comment: @Patrick the spelling error was when i was creating the question in the source is spelled correctly. if I render `dashboard-account`, it renders correctly but its the old view... if I change this back to `dashboard.account`, it still looks for `dashboard-account`

Comment: @Devon in the route definition. `Route::get('/dashboard/account', function () {echo 'aaa'; });`, but still seems to execute `DashboardController@account`

Comment: And route:list still shows you have it pointing to the controller?  That indicates you have some problem but it's not caching.  Are you sure you don't have the routes duplicated somewhere?

Comment: @Miguel Pinto Can you please confirm are you working in the same dir?

Comment: @Devon i was loading dashboard routes in a `/routes/dashboard.php` file which was required in the `/routes/web.php`, now i placed the routes definitions in `web.php`, deleted the `require` statement and saved the file, now i throws an error saying the dashboard.php file doesnt exists...

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal yes, i think yes, otherwise i couldnt run `php artisan`, im working on the project root `c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject`

Comment: Try for the fun of it, try `php artisan view:clear` and see if that changes anything

Comment: @Patrick just did it, still not working... im getting crazy... I was able to run the closure and echoing 'aaaa', but when i set the action to the route 'DashboardController@account` (which only dumps the Request Object) it still show the `View [dashboard-account] not found`...

Comment: @Devon, I was able to fixed this, I delete de DashboardController.php file and created a new one.. it works now... Still not knowing what cause this...

Comment: @Patrick, I was able to fix this, I deleted the DashboardController.php file and created a new one.. it works now... Still not knowing what cause this...

Comment: You either have opcache enabled (but rare to have it enabled for cli) or you have some issue with your filesystem.  Hard to know what without seeing your environment, but it's clearly not set up properly for development.